# XSLT (1.0) How to preserve html tags when wrapping element value in a CDATA tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, onix

I have an XML with Text elements that can include tagged text and depending on the elements attribute value i know if the content is CDATA encapsulated or XHTML.

As i cannot have/create any child elements in the Text element i will need to encapsulate if i get XHTML.

This is just 1 of many elements i need to transform in my XSLT

A short xml sample

```
  <ONIXMessage release="3.0" xmlns="http://ns.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference">
  <Product>
    <CollateralDetail>
      <TextContent>
        <Text textformat="05">
          <p>Requires internet connection for purchase, plus iPod or other Audible-compatible player or iTunes software on Mac OS X or Windows</p>
        </Text>
      </TextContent>
    </CollateralDetail>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <CollateralDetail>
      <TextContent>
        <Text textformat="02"><![CDATA["Nogle dyr er farlige. Nogle dyr kan slå dig ihjel!"
Hvis det stod til Claras mor, var Clara aldrig blevet vildheks. Hun er bange for at Clara skal komme noget til, og det viser sig at der er en god grund. Den vilde verden ER et farligt sted – ikke mindst nu hvor Bravita Blodsunge er ved at bryde fri af det fængsel der har holdt hende fanget i 400 år ...

"Blodsungen" er fjerde bog i serien om Clara, hendes kærlighed til dyr og hendes kamp for at overleve som vildheks i en verden hvor magi ikke ligefrem er barnemad.]]></Text>
      </TextContent>
    </CollateralDetail>
  </Product>
</ONIXMessage>
```

I finally tried this and it does somehow achieve the goal. It is just that html tags are not preserved.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:onix="http://ns.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl onix xsi">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<!--  cdata-section-elements="onix:BiographicalNote onix:Text" -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node() ">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//onix:TextContent/onix:Text ">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="//onix:TextContent/onix:Text/@textformat='05'">
                <xsl:element name="Text" xmlns="http://ns.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference" >
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will produce the following (note the

tag is gone in the first text)

```
<ONIXMessage release="3.0" xmlns="http://ns.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference">
  <Product>
    <CollateralDetail>
      <TextContent>
        <TextType>11</TextType>
        <ContentAudience>02</ContentAudience>
        <Text><![CDATA[
          Requires internet connection for purchase, plus iPod or other Audible-compatible player or iTunes software on Mac OS X or Windows
        ]]></Text>
      </TextContent>
    </CollateralDetail>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <CollateralDetail>
      <TextContent>
        <TextType>03</TextType>
        <ContentAudience>00</ContentAudience>
        <Text><![CDATA["Nogle dyr er farlige. Nogle dyr kan slå dig ihjel!"
Hvis det stod til Claras mor, var Clara aldrig blevet vildheks. Hun er bange for at Clara skal komme noget til, og det viser sig at der er en god grund. Den vilde verden ER et farligt sted – ikke mindst nu hvor Bravita Blodsunge er ved at bryde fri af det fængsel der har holdt hende fanget i 400 år ...

"Blodsungen" er fjerde bog i serien om Clara, hendes kærlighed til dyr og hendes kamp for at overleve som vildheks i en verden hvor magi ikke ligefrem er barnemad.]]></Text>
      </TextContent>
    </CollateralDetail>
  </Product>
</ONIXMessage>
```

I have also tried to use 
cdata-section-elements="onix:Text"

But the output becomes really odd with multiple cdata tags in the output for 1 element and the only thing it doesn't encapsulate is actually the text i want to encapsulate

```
<BiographicalNote textformat="05"><![CDATA[
  ]]><p>A crime writer for over thirty years, Ruth Rendell has won one Crime Writers’ Association Silver Dagger Award, two Gold Daggers and, the supreme accolade, the Crime Writers’ Diamond Award for her outstanding contribution to the genre.</p><![CDATA[
]]></BiographicalNote>
```

How do i solve what i need to achieve? 
Why are the html tags removed from the element value when i try to encapsulate the text in the code i did (.. and is that even the right approach ?!)

Comment: What happens when you do `<xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>` instead of `<xsl:value-of select="current()"/>`?

Comment: It will encapsulate the full element
        <![CDATA[<Text textformat="05">
          <p>Requires internet connection for purchase, plus iPod or other Audible-compatible player or iTunes software on Mac OS X or Windows</p>
        </Text>]]>

Comment: I assume it has something to do with how i apply the template. Problem is that this is just 1 of many element transformations in the full XSLT and i will need to consider all. Im really a stylesheet rookie :-)

Comment: Oops! I meant to say do `<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>` which will then only select the child nodes.

Comment: Bam!! Spot on. It did the trick. Any idea why value-of removed the tags (as i assume this was the basic problem) Is it simply the nature of that function ?? as i said im a stylesheet rookie. I would like to upvote you (how?)

Comment: Yes. `xsl:value-of` returns only the text value of a node, but does not copy the nodes themselves.

Comment: Do note that in general the use of CDATA ("don't parse this as XML") shows a deeper problem in the design or the process chain: some application in the chain can't handle correctly an XML instance.

Comment: You are somewhat right Alejandro. It shouldn't really be necessary to change the layout/schema in the first place... This standard does have some flaws.
More ways to express marked up text is one of them i think. But considering the overall design CDATA is the most seamless i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Tim C https://stackoverflow.com/users/7585/tim-c

It seemed that i didn't fully understand the nature of `value-of`
The solution was pretty close.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:onix="http://ns.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl onix xsi">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<!--  cdata-section-elements="onix:BiographicalNote onix:Text" -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node() ">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//onix:TextContent/onix:Text ">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="//onix:TextContent/onix:Text/@textformat='05'">
                <xsl:element name="Text" xmlns="http://ns.editeur.org/onix/3.0/reference" >
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It's not only your understanding of xsl:value-of that was faulty, you're also still thinking of XML as something that contains tags. XSLT doesn't see tags, it sees a tree of nodes (the output of the XML parser), and understanding the distinction is really important.

Comment: Thank you for the input Michael. Might have misused the xml terminology in my way of asking the question. Sorry about that. Will definitely keep the importancy of the distinction in mind.